# Row Header For Cross Tab Report In Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have designed one crystal cross tab report.it is displaying like this

```
       col1 col2 col3
```

row1 row11 val1 val2 val3

row2 row21 val1 val2 val3

but i want heading for the row also i.e. i want report like this

name1 name2 col1 col2 col3

row1     row11     val1 val2 val3

row2     row21    val1 val2 val3

can any one help?

Answer (score 8):

Ryans solution only works for the first page, but he is on the right track.

This solution works for all pages

[image: Crosstab with headers above the rows on each page]

1) The crosstab needs to be in its own group section header.

2) you need to have 2 page header sections.

Section 2 (page header a)  contains all the text you want to appear on each page including the row header.  In my case i have the row headers "Table  Curr MinBet"

Section 2 (page header a) needs to have the "Underlay Following sections" checkbox checked from Section expert.  This makes CR display the page header section underneath the crosstab.

3) PageHeaderSection2 (page header b) is used to space the crosstab to the right position.
Without this, the page header and row header appear underneath the crosstab report rather than above it.

I am running CR version 13_0_1 for visual studio 2010

Comment: Just to precise the @dummyGroup you're using for Grouping. I tried to put anything as the formula, like "1", but Crystal (in VB2008) didn't let me choose this formula for grouping. So I figured you must use at least one database field in the formula. So to get always the same result (to get only one instance of the group), I put: [Field1] = [Field1]. This always result at true, so just one result.

Answer (score 3):

You can just overlay a text object as the heading.

[image: Like this]

Comment: I was hoping that CR 2008 would have more options because it added a 'calculated member' feature to CrossTabs.  Alas, they haven't added a feature to support a 'top-left-corner label'.  Your approach seems pretty reasonable.